# Auto Assign Space and Org to new CF Users

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

we have a cloud foundry demo installation for customers. Customers are able to create an account. Now, I would like t assign automatically a specific org and space incl. roles to every new user.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing out of the box that does this. I can't see anything in the [events API](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/245/) that you could plug into either.

Comment: A good place to also ask would be the Cloud Foundry Community Slack. There must be a way as public CF's like PWS & Bluemix have that functionality - https://slack.cloudfoundry.org/

Comment: @AlexEvade PWS and BlueMix wrap the user-create call, and orchestrate the other actions. So one could do something like youngm suggests.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a web application that users go to create their account then use uaa apis and cloud controller apis to create and assign the user to whatever you want.  This application can use uaa client accounts with appropriate authorities.

If you only want users to create their accounts using your application I believe you can tell uaa to disable self service links in the uaa ui using "login.self_service_links_enabled=false" and can probably stop people from creating their own accounts on the CLI by removing the "scim.write" scope from the cf client.